# NSTimer not operating as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I hope this to be a simple fix, you tell me.

What I have is a class IVAR *timer of type NSTimer. When an IBAction is performed, a method is called that contains this code:

```
if (timer) timer = nil;
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(removeOverlay) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

In the same class, I have a method:

```
- (void)removeOverlay {
...
}
```

That isn't fired after the time interval of .2 seconds.

Might you know what the problem is here?

Comment: Gets called multiple times instead of once?

Comment: It gets called only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the `timer` the instance of `NSTimer` is not released meanwhile.
2. `removeOverlay` looks like it updates some UI. Make shure you call it on main thread.
3. Put a breakpoint in the `removeLayout` method to see if it fires.
4. You are not scheduling the timer. Replace the `timerWithTimeInterval` with `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`

To perform code on main thread (allows UI updating):

```
- (void)removeOverlay {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     // update ui
  });
}
```

More on [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: it does do UI, however I know that it is not called because of an NSLog

Comment: I improved the answer. "You are not scheduling the timer. Replace the timerWithTimeInterval with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval"

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
 [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

The timers work by placing the calls at the appropriate points in the run loop.

Comment: hm Ive used them before with no problems and without an NSRunLoop

Comment: @EliGregory - You probably used `scheduledTimer...`

Answer (score 1):

Since no one mentioned it, an alternative to adding the timer to a run loop is to use the fire method:

```
[timer fire];
```

Comment: I've also tried this, the documentation claims that this does an *additional* fire and is not the actual start of the timer

Comment: I haven't read any of this in the documentation. Maybe the fire is additional if you used created the timer with scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval.

Answer (score 0):

If it only gets called once I'd use `[self performSelector:@selector(removeOverlay) afterDelay:(seconds you want to delay the use the method removeOverlay)];`

Comment: what class contains that method? It doesn't appear to be a class of UIViewController because I can't call it

Comment: It actually is a UIViewController

Comment: Is it deprecated? I was thrown an error when I tried to run it. (It would be awesome if it is, I imagine it has quite a lot of uses)